# Lower Timeframe confirmations working separately, but then when consolidating does not work. Pinescript, Tradingview

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api

I am having an issue with adding conditions from lower time frames on a higher timeframe, thank you in advance for your help.

--------- WORKING
This works and gives me information in the labels created, Example label is showing 30min (true,true, false, false):

```
var label long1 = na
var label long2 = na
var label short1 = na
var label short2 = na

bclose1  = request.security_lower_tf(syminfo.tickerid, "15", longSignal)
bclose2  = request.security_lower_tf(syminfo.tickerid, "30", longSignal)
sclose1  = request.security_lower_tf(syminfo.tickerid, "15", shortSignal)
sclose2  = request.security_lower_tf(syminfo.tickerid, "30", shortSignal)

longlabl1  = "15m - Longs" + "\n" + str.tostring(bclose1)
longlabl2  = "30m - Longs" + "\n" + str.tostring(bclose2) 
shortlabl1 = "15m - Shorts" + "\n" + str.tostring(sclose1)
shortlabl2 = "30m - Shorts" + "\n" + str.tostring(sclose2) 

if bar_index == last_bar_index
    long1 := label.new(bar_index, low, text=longlabl1, color=color.green, textcolor=color.white, style=label.style_label_up)

if bar_index == last_bar_index
    long2 := label.new(bar_index + 25, low, text=longlabl2, color=color.green, textcolor=color.white, style=label.style_label_up)
    
if bar_index == last_bar_index
    short1 := label.new(bar_index, high , text=shortlabl1, color=color.red, textcolor=color.white, style=label.style_label_down)

if bar_index == last_bar_index
    short2 := label.new(bar_index + 25, high, text=shortlabl2, color=color.red, textcolor=color.white, style=label.style_label_down)
```

-------------------------- NOT WORKING

The change I want to make is to consolidate the signals into one signal:

```
//Consolidated Long signal from 15m, 30m, and current which is 120m
bclose1  = (request.security_lower_tf(syminfo.tickerid, "15", longSignal))  and (request.security_lower_tf(syminfo.tickerid, "30", longSignal))  and longSignal

//Consolidated Short signal from 15m, 30m, and current which is 120m
sclose1  = (request.security_lower_tf(syminfo.tickerid, "15", shortSignal)) and (request.security_lower_tf(syminfo.tickerid, "30", shortSignal)) and shortSignal

longlabl1  = "All 3 Longs" + "\n" + str.tostring(bclose1)
shortlabl1 = "All 3 Shorts" + "\n" + str.tostring(sclose1)

if bar_index == last_bar_index
    long1 := label.new(bar_index, low, text=longlabl1, color=color.green, textcolor=color.white, style=label.style_label_up)

if bar_index == last_bar_index
    short1 := label.new(bar_index, high , text=shortlabl1, color=color.red, textcolor=color.white, style=label.style_label_down)
```

----------- ERROR
Cannot Call "Operator and" with argument 'exper1'='call 'request.security_lower_tf' (bool[])'. An argument of 'bool[]' type was used but a 'simple bool' is expected;

Not sure what a 'simple bool' is, but I am guessing it is a true or false and this is a more complex bool.

I am wondering if putting things in an array would help, but I'm not sure.

Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

"I am wondering if putting things in an array would help"
Indeed, that's what you must do.
This function returns an array and not a single value
Which makes sense, because when we're for example on a 5m chart querying 1m candles data, this function will return an array of five 1m candles

Cheers
Dave